# KnockoutJS: Observable Object in object in viewmodel not refreshing

Tags: knockout.js

I am experiencing a problem with knockoutJS data binding by observables in the viewmodel. If I try to access a specific observable (which is an object) property in an object in an object in my viewmodel, the value doesn't seem to update.

```
<li data-bind="attr: {id: 'option-' + modalData().modalid }, modal: {template: 'modal-template',  modalid: modalData().modalid, title: modalData().title, options: {heading: modalData().title, trigger: 'click'}, customElement: $('.modal-dropdown') }">
  <a href="#">Open Modal</a>
</li>
```

To initialize my modal dialog correctly, I need to provide an options property with the configuration. To show the correct title, I need to access the title of modalData(). The problem appears when I try to open a different modal dialog after opening one - the binding of title does not seem to work correctly in the options-property.

So after clicking a different modal, the binding of the id attribute is correctly updated, but the heading will display the value of the initially clicked modal dialog.

Does anyone know how I can fix this or what I am doing wrong? I can only guess it has to do with the fact that I am accessing the observable inside an object inside an option and that somehow makes it weird?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Could you show us enough of the code so that we can try it ourselves and help you out?

Comment: Total side note. But, you're doing WAY too much in your `data-bind`. Make a `pureComputed` that returns a `{}` to provide the data for the `attr` binding.

Answer (score 0):

Modal's are a tricky thing to accomplish in the [MVVM paradigm](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#mvvm_and_view_models).

The `data-attribute` approach that many of the modal libraries out there provide, should be seen as a very introductory/simple/high-level usage of the library. Most times, you should skip straight to the "API" section of the docs (unless of course your use-case is DEAD simple).

I've always had most success encapsulating the logic to do this in a [Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), which you pass in an object of "options".

For example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {};

        function onClick(){
            TheModalLibrary.OpenModal(options);
        };

        element.onclick = onClick;
    }
};
```

Which you would use as such (it even looks "cleaner" doesn't it?):

```
<li>
  <a href="#" data-bind="modal: modalData">Open Modal</a>
</li>
```

**Couple important things to note here**.

1. If `modalData` is observable, or you expect it's value to change, and this is something you need to reflect in the modal. Change `init` to `update`. This will force the binding to re-evaulate when the dependencies (`valueAccessor`) change.
2. This is an entirely conrtrived example, and should be seen as more pseudo-code. If you provide me with the actual modal library you're using, I would be happy to provide a more specific code sample.
3. The base knockout bindings should be seen as a starting point. As soon as things begin getting even remotely complex, you should be looking to expand on the tools knockout provides. A la, [Custom Binding's](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), [Component's](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/components.html) and [Template's](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/templates.html).

The big take away from all of this, is that DOM oriented things like modal's, or any integrations with JavaScript libraries, are typically best suited for a [Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) application. In fact, anything that isn't explicitly "MVVM" belongs in a [Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).